# Не работает Cron, в Laravel 5.4 + Docker

Tags: php, laravel, cron, docker

Обновили Laravel 5.3 до Laravel 5.4 используя этот контейнер https://github.com/shin1x1/docker-laravel-on-php7-apache

PHP изменилось с 5.X до 7.
В кроне стояла такая задача

```
* * * * * php /var/www/laravel/artisan schedule:run >>/dev/null 2>&1
```

На предыдущем билде все работало нормально, а теперь перестало

Сама команда, если запустить ее из SSH

```
php /var/www/laravel/artisan schedule:run >>/dev/null 2>&1
```

работает нормально.

Если перенаправить вывод ошибок из крона в файл, например

```
  * * * * * php /var/www/laravel/artisan schedule:run > /etc/log/faillog
```

То в файле получаем такое

```
/bin/sh: 1: php: not found
```

Вопрос - почему крон не видит PHP и куда копать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `/bin/sh: 1: php: not found`

очевидно, что надо **либо** указать полный путь к программе *php*, узнать который можно, например, такой командой:

```
$ which php
```

**либо** добавить в начало файла с *cron*-заданием переопределение значения переменной окружения `PATH`:

```
PATH=значение
```

нужное значение можно узнать, например, такой командой:

```
$ echo $PATH
```

p.s. приведённые команды, естественно, надо выполнять внутри контейнера.

Comment: Долго не мог добраться до этого компа, но все сработало